Building a new plugin for capacitor for version 4.X
I have a capacitorJS project which uses capacitor 4.7.0. I need to develop a unique plugin.
The problem is that today there is version 6.0.0 and I can not find a way to create a template plugin for version 4.7.0. in capacitorJS 4.X documentation it says to run the following to create the plugin :
npm init @capacitor/plugin@latest
however when doing so it creates a 6.0.0 version.
Any way to overcome this ?

You can simply use an old version of that CLI:
npm init @capacitor/plugin@0.9.0

Version 0.9.0 is for Capacitor 4 (see GitHub).
